# replacing residential circulator pump flanges with shutoff flanges

Tags: plumbing, water-circulating-heating, pipe-fitting

About 15 years ago the local heating company installed a new boiler and put on a standard TACO circulator pump with standard flanges that do not isolate the pump; on the boiler side the flange is threaded onto a 1" black iron pipe nipple, and on the far side it is threaded onto 1" copper male adapter.  I don't know what sealant compound was used.

Is it reasonable to expect the threads of the black iron pipe and of the copper male adapter to be in good, reusable condition the flanges have been removed and the threads have been wire-brushed?  Or is it typical that the sealing compound, whatever it is, will have hardened over that time and will resist being brushed away.

Comment: the title of your post does not match the question asked

Answer (score 1):

You will need new **pipe dope** (the thread sealing compound.)

The old stuff should be removable without great effort.